# SOA maven archetype is not letting me create a project using Maven. Please advise

Tags: oracle, maven, soa, maven-archetype

I am trying to create a soa project using maven and running in to an issue. I have been following oracle documentaiton on this and could not move forward any help?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/maven/building-oracle-soa-suite-and-oracle-business-process-management-projects-maven.html#GUID-D8DD6A09-34BF-49AE-A676-60F690E75691

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.oracle.soa.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=oracle-soa-application -DarchetypeVersion=12.1.3-0-0

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.oracle.soa.archetype:oracle-soa-application:12.1.3-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the archetype cannot be found.

First you have to know is, archetype is just a prototype of a Maven project, preconfiguring some settings and leaving you with a "ready to get your hands dirty" project.

To find dependencies, Maven looks up defined repositories and downloads container into your local repository upon finding. Maven dependencies should be defined in your POM.xml like follows:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.soa.archetype</groupId>
      <artifactId>oracle-soa-application</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
   </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

If you already defined that in your POM, and it still doesn't work, i suppose you are working with the [Maven Standard Repository,](https://mvnrepository.com/) where it seems to not be included.

To add the oracle repository that seems to be intended for that and other projects on the website you linked, i would suggest to try to configure the [Orcale Maven Repository](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/maven/configuring-oracle-maven-repository.html#GUID-19C4FA37-9F37-4F59-8FAF-57FF47698E3A).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I dont have any pom at the moment, I am trying to create a new SOA maven project using maven.

Comment: Oops pushed enter too early, what I mean to say is should i be adding these to any  settings.xml ? I am following the video below in creating and am running the step at 1:17 min. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHFMT3mEV74 . When I check the repository I have installed earlier using the plugin it has the pom and the jar file at this location C:\Users\XXX\.m2\repository\com\oracle\soa\archetype\oracle-soa-project\12.2.1-3-0

Answer (score 0):

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.oracle.servicebus.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=oracle-servicebus-application should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).